# Wagtail and Django

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, wagtail

I'm experienced with Django and I've just started looking into wagtail integration in order to provide a better UX to the content management.

Let's say I have an existing Django app and I would like to keep the same structure but this time the contents can be managed from the wagtail admin panel instead of the Django one.

Is there a way to let's say created a parallel Model which mirrors the existing Django Model. So I add contents from wagtail admin and it will add those content to the same DB schema .

I know you can created a 1 to 1 relation to the existing django model, that might be one way of approaching it I think. Not sure what the best way to do so ??

Also it seems like you will have to provide an html template for each Model correct ?

When does it make sense to use it ?
Do you actually save time instead of crating you own UI ?
What are the alternatives there ?

Thank you in advance